# CSS3 rotate wobbles

Tags: css, css-animations

I have below code and I am trying to rotate an image 360deg. But the rotation wobbles.

```css
.pully {
  position: absolute;
  right: 3.7em;
  bottom: 1em;
  z-index: 11;
  animation-name: clockwiseSpinner;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}

.line {
  position: absolute;
  right: 145px;
  bottom: 10px;
  height: 200px;
  border-right: 2px solid red;
}

@-webkit-keyframes clockwiseSpinner {
  from {-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg)}
  to {-webkit-transform: rotate(360deg)}
}
```

```html
<div class="line"></div>
<img class="pully" src="https://s8.postimg.cc/vax8le4x1/p-pully.png" alt="">
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a65hox1r/4/)

Any idea how can I remove that wobbleness?

Comment: what do you mean by the wobble? It rotates the image as intended, the smoothness of the appearance would probably only be affected by a more-rounded image?

Comment: Simply put, the image itself is wobbly, or off-center. Open it in an image editor and rotate it, see? I guess being (1 pixel) wider than it is high doesn't exactly help!

Comment: @enhzflep  i agree, it's the image, not the code. Oh, should have added that "infinite" is incorrectly spelt in the given code...

Comment: @enhzflep that does not work either. rachel gallen I am not sure what do you mean the rounded image.

Comment: @null - what does not work? I suggested no action be taken. Simply put, the image you have is no good for this purpose without modification (which I wouldn't bother with)

Comment: Here I changed the image but still the same issue. http://jsfiddle.net/a65hox1r/17/

Comment: Quite simply, your circle isn't centered in the square box.

Answer (score 5):

"It's the image" is right, but not entirely. Since the `img` *element* is an *inline element* by *default*, it's given the `vertical-align: baseline` *property / value* pair, which visually results and comes with a little *whitespace* or *"margin-bottom"* underneath it (this can be easily seen when giving it a border, as you've already done), which of course is the culprit and causes that wobble effect.

So in order to get rid of the issue, just change the *default value* of `baseline` to e.g. `top`, `middle` or `bottom`, as these are the *"certain values"* to use.

Another way of solving it would simply be displaying it as `block` *level element*, where the `vertical-align` *property* has no place.

*Note:* If you apply these changes to your first example or original post, the issue still persists, therefore it really is the "image's fault".

```css
.pully, .pully_left {
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  right: 3.8em;
  bottom: 1em;
  z-index: 11;
  animation-name: clockwiseSpinner;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  animation-iteration-count: 4;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  /* shorthand: "animation: clockwiseSpinner 1s ease-in 4;" */
}

.pully_left {right: 10.25em}

.line {
  position: absolute;
  right: 145px;
  bottom: 10px;
  height: 200px;
  border-right: 2px solid red;
}

.pully > img {vertical-align: bottom} /* or "top" / "middle" or "display: block" */

@-webkit-keyframes clockwiseSpinner {
  /*from {-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg)} unnecessary */
  to {-webkit-transform: rotate(360deg)}
}
```

```html
<div class="line"></div>

<div class="pully">
  <img src="https://s8.postimg.cc/u6gyll9ud/p-pully-center.png" alt="">
</div>

<div class="pully_left"> <!-- for comparison -->
  <img src="https://s8.postimg.cc/u6gyll9ud/p-pully-center.png" alt="">
</div>

<!-- <img class="pully" src="https://s8.postimg.cc/vax8le4x1/p-pully.png" alt=""> -->
```

Comment: It was the `vertical-align: bottom` for me!